# When does Spark evict broadcasted dataframe from Executors?

Tags: apache-spark, broadcast, evict

I have a doubt, about when we broadcast a dataframe.

Copies of broadcasted dataframe are sent to each Executor.

So, when does Spark evict these copies from each Executor ?

Answer (score 0):

I find this topic functionally easy to understand, but the manuals harder to follow technically and there are improvements always in the offing.

My take:

> - There is a `ContextCleaner` that is running on the Driver for every Spark App.
> - It gets created immediately started when the `SparkContext` commences.
> - It is more about all sorts of objects in Spark.
> - The `ContextCleaner` thread cleans RDD, shuffle, and *broadcast states*, Accumulators using `keepCleaning` method that runs always
>   from this class. It decides which objects needs eviction due to no longer being
>   referenced and these get placed on a list. It calls various methods, such
>   as `registerShuffleForCleanup`. That is to say a check is made to see if there are no `alive root` objects pointing to a given object; if so, then that object is eligible for clean-up, eviction.
> - `context-cleaner-periodic-gc` asynchronously requests the standard JVM garbage collector. Periodic runs of this are started when
>   `ContextCleaner` starts and stopped when `ContextCleaner` terminates.
> - Spark makes use of the standard Java GC.

This https://mallikarjuna_g.gitbooks.io/spark/content/spark-service-contextcleaner.html is a good reference next to the Spark official docs.